# 2-step animated transition in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I'd like to make a custom view transition in SwiftUI, animated in 2 steps:

**Presenting child**

1. Fade out parent (opacity to 0)
2. (Then) fade in child and slide from bottom

**Dismissing child**

1. Fade out child and slide to bottom
2. (Then) fade in parent

**Demo (created artificially)**

[image: Demo]

Base code:

```
struct TransitionTestView: View {
    @State var presented = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if presented {
                Button("Hide", action: { presented = false })
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(.purple)
            }
            else {
                Button("Show", action: { presented = true })
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(.orange)
            }
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
}
```

I've experimented with:

- Different placements of the `animation` modifier: to the ZStack, or to each element individually
- Applying the animation directly to the transition: `.opacity.animation(.linear(duration: 1).delay(1))`

But I couldn't make it work. Any help appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach can be using transaction transformation by injecting additional delay to main animation for each phase.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
ZStack {
    VStack {  // << animating container
        if presented {
            Button("Hide", action: { presented = false })
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.purple)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        }
    }
    .transaction { // << transform animation for direct transition
        $0.animation = $0.animation?.delay(presented ? 1.2 : 0)
    }

    VStack { // << animating container
        if !presented {
            Button("Show", action: { presented = true })
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.orange)
                .transition(.opacity)
        }
    }
    .transaction { // << transform animation for reverse transition
        $0.animation = $0.animation?.delay(presented ? 0 : 1.2)
    }
}
.animation(.linear(duration: 1), value: presented)   // << main !!
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestSeparatedTransitions.swift)